# Apache Reverse Proxy Preserve URL even after redirect

Tags: apache, webserver, reverse-proxy, redirect, mod-proxy

I have an apache reverse proxy setup from where I am redirecting to a completely different URL. The destination URL is a cloud-hosted service different from the Apache installation location. The redirect is happening properly. But how do I preserve the original URL and mask this new cloud-hosted URL?

This is my apache httpd.conf on Oracle Linux

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so

ProxyRequests Off

<VirtualHost *:80>
     ProxyPreserveHost On
     ServerName xxx.xxx.xx.xx:80
     ServerAlias https://sample-url.cloud.com/
     Redirect / https://sample-url.cloud.com/

</VirtualHost>
```

How to achieve this.

Comment: A `Redirect` has _nothing_ to do with proxying... You want to take a look at apaches proxy modujle and the ``ProxyPass``/``ProxyPassReverse`` directives. Take a look at the official documentation. It is of _excellent_ quality and comes with helpful examples.